# Disable the wysiwyg "Switch to HTML editing mode" button for specific module only

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions, adminhtml

I am trying to find a "clean" way to disable/remove this button from the TinyMCE content editor in my module.

Is there any way to override this file in a specific module only
/js/mage/adminhtml/wysiwyg/tiny_mce/setup.js ?

I tried to put this in the design part of my module, but looks like it is not working.

Any idea?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Untested but here's my idea:

Add a javascript file to your module that sets a global variable.
In /js/mage/adminhtml/wysiwyg/tiny_mce/setup.js make a check function to see if the global variable is set and then disable or enable the button.

Alternatively you could overwrite the javascript function directly: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13379034/how-to-override-product-js-file-in-magento